# Compare two lists of different sObjects without double loops in Apex

Tags: design-patterns, salesforce, apex

I need to check a list of custom objects (instance), to find matches in another list of custom objects (template). A match is where the fields contain the same values, or value is null on the template. The existing code has a double loop like:

```
for(instance theInstance : theInstanceList){
    for(template thTemplate: theTemplateList){
        if((theInstanve.field1 = theTemplate.field1 || theTemplate.field1 == null) &&{
           (theInstanve.field2 = theTemplate.field2 || theTemplate.field2 == null) &&{
            and so on for 8-10 fields ....{
           ){
                Carry out requirements ........{
           }
     }
}
```

It's pretty inefficient when there are lots of records. Any thoughts on a nicer solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would try, as a partial solution (may be brittle depending on your requirements):

1. convert theTemplateList to JSON
2. loop through theInstanceList
   a. convert each instance to JSON
   b. check if the JSON template list "contains" (string method) the JSON instance

That way you would loop just once and in a single comparison do the check for all 10 fields.

Here are the assumptions that you may have to deal with:

- fields from instance and template have the same names
- fields are in the same order in the JSON string
- if a field is null it will not show up in the JSON string
- you need to match all 10 fields
- if the instance field is populated and the respective template is not, the comparison will fail

If JSON doesn't work for any of the above reasons, you could still create a formula field concatenating the field values and do the "contains" using the formula fields instead of JSON.